# how to create RDLC form dynamically in run time and how to save it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

how to create RDLC form dynamically in run time and how to save it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the Report Definition Language  and based on that create XML file and save it as rdlc extension. If you want to handle report events, you need emit to generate dynamic .net code.