# how create a RDLC file dynamically during run time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

how create a RDLC file dynamically during run time?

Comment: Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/q/4942698/375958

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437548/what-is-the-best-way-to-dynamically-generate-rdlc-report-definitions-at-runtime/3446775#3446775